# icon with text vertically aligned

Tags: css

I am trying to do a responsive image icon and belonged text aligned vertically. But once I want to set the text size of whatever size, the icon resizes as well. As well as if I write longer text, the icon resizes as well. I made it this way but I believe there must be some simple way. I just want an icon image where I can set width in percentage and text (label) where I can set font-size.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ra7zbwwe/

css:
    #cat_filter_box {
        width:100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

```
.filter_item {
   float:left;
}

.filter_item_icon_box {
    display: inline-block;
    width:30%;
}


.filter_item:after {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.filter_item_text {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:1em;
}
```

html:

```
     <div id="cat_filter_box">
     <div class="filter_item"><a href="#">
         <span class="filter_item_icon_box"><img src="http://czechtop.cz/images/osobnosti.png" width="100%" style="vertical-align:middle" /></span>
         <span class="filter_item_text">Textlength</span></a>
     </div>

     <div class="filter_item"><a href="#">
         <span class="filter_item_icon_box"><img src="http://czechtop.cz/images/osobnosti.png" width="100%" style="vertical-align:middle" /></span>
         <span class="filter_item_text">Textlength of item two</span></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You must understand that using a percentage width, it's relative width of the parent element. Meaning if your text is longer, therefor the parent element is longer, thus your 30% will increase. Perhaps you simply could set `max-width: 20px;`

Comment: Exactly as Kay said. Let your icon width behave independently and let its parent in contrast adjust to the changes in responsive behavior without the need of a %. This is because adding % to the parent will affect the child image in ways you may not desire, unless all you have inside the parent is an image (which you do not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exchange `.filter_item_icon_box`'s width to **px**, instead of **percentage**

```
.filter_item_icon_box {
    display: inline-block;
    width:50px;
}
```

**[Online Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8c046L05/)**

Comment: Thank you all guys for the explanation, I've set the width of the icon box to fixed pixels 50px and it works fine, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome @LukášJežek . There's no better way of saying thank you on stackoverflow by setting an answer as correct or up voting it =)